# Хочу написать .bat файл, который будет запускать DosBox, сразу прописывая в нем некоторые команды

Tags: bat

хочу написать .bat файл, который будет запускать DosBox и сразу прописывать в нем команды:
Например, запустить DosBox и сразу создать там виртуальный диск.
mount d: c:"Путь"

Comment: Вопрос странный, вернее не совсем понятный Ну пишите, кто же Вам мешает? ))) А если Вы про то как это делается, то для начала посмотрите статью про установку и настройку DosBox вот [здесь](https://ixbt.games/articles/2021/03/28/dosbox-dlya-cainikov-instrukciya-po-zapusku-klassiceskix-igr-pod-windows.html). Возможно тут уже есть ответы на все Ваши вопросы.

Comment: Не корректно написал вопрос, да, я имел в виду, как это сделать. Спасибо, в вашей ссылке нашел ответ на свой вопрос.